# Inserting rows in an empty array using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hello im currently trying to convert this array

```
test=np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[3,0]])
```

and using Manhattan distance to convert this array into this shape

```
[0., 1., 2., 3.] 
[1., 0., 1., 4.]
[2., 1., 0., 3.,
[3., 4., 3., 0.]
```

the code goes like this

```
list_x=[]
newarray=np.array([])
length=len(test)
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length):
        print('i=',i)
        print('j=',j)
        var=sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(test[i],test[j]))
        list_x.append(var)
    newarray= np.append(newarray,list_x,axis = 0) 
    list_x=[]
```

but the outcome of the code keeps giving me this:

```
array([0., 1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 1., 4., 2., 1., 0., 3., 3., 4., 3., 0.])
```

is there a problem in my np.append() that prevent to convert it to 4*4 shap array ?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with scikit-learn's [`manhattan_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances.html) to obtain all pairwise manhattan distances simplifying the above to a single function call:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import manhattan_distances

manhattan_distances(test)
array([[0., 1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 0., 1., 4.],
       [2., 1., 0., 3.],
       [3., 4., 3., 0.]])
```

---

If you wanted to obtain the distance with a for loop, I'd suggest you to use python lists instead. In order to end up with a nested list, generate an inner list with the distances of a row to the others, and append it to an outer list on each iteration:

```
out=[]
for i in range(length):
    new_row = []
    for j in range(length):
        var=sum(abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(test[i],test[j]))
        new_row.append(var)
    out.append(new_row)

print(out)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1, 4], [2, 1, 0, 3], [3, 4, 3, 0]]
```

Comment: or use your original ... z = np.array([0., 1., 2., 3., 1., 0., 1., 4., 2., 1., 0., 3., 3., 4., 3., 0.]) and z.reshape(4,4)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is using Scipy:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
cdist(test,test,'cityblock')
```

output:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [1. 0. 1. 4.]
 [2. 1. 0. 3.]
 [3. 4. 3. 0.]]
```

---

**Comparison**:

```
#@ehsan's solution
def m1(test):
  return cdist(test,test,'cityblock')

#@yatu's solution
def m2(test):
  return manhattan_distances(test)

in_ = [np.random.randint(0,10,(n,2)) for n in [10,100,1000,10000]]
```

For large arrays they seem to have similar performance, but for smaller array (around 1000 rows) **m1** seems faster.

[image]

Comment: I know the cdist function but the object of this task is to right the Manhattan distance by hand and I have a problem only in the append function

Comment: @RAbeeq Then I misunderstood the problem. Do you have to use loops? you can still implement it with numpy without loops. Looping an array is not advised in general and is slow. If you need loops, I think Yatu's answer covers it. If you do not have to use loops, I can help implementing it with arrays.

Comment: no need but thank your for you help I really thank you